# Why does the browser automatically scroll down to a '#hashhyperlinks' and how can we stop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hash hyperlink that is used to show specific jquery based on the hash given.

The problem is that the browser automatically scrolls to the DOM element that has the class or id...how can we stop this?

Comment: You can use preventDefault for the event.

Comment: how about some code? It is basically default behavior. a #link is called an anchor.

Comment: Problem is the hash hyperlink is called on a different page...does that mean i have to change the id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't give your element that id
- Or call `.preventDefault()` in the click event of the link

  ```
  $("a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For that, you should use:

**preventDefault();**

> The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an
>   element from happening. For example: Prevent a submit button from
>   submitting a form Prevent a link from following the URL

Find more about it @ [w3schools : event.preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

**Usage:**

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```